# Why does my program(code chef- two numbers) crash when i give higher values to variables

Tags: c++, algorithm

Question: https://www.codechef.com/problems/TWONMS.
My code:

```
 #include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<algorithm>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int t,a,b,n,c,d,FinalNumber;
cin>>t;
for(int i= 0;i<t;i++){
cin>>a;
cin>>b;
cin>>n;
c=a;
d=b;
int n1 = n/2;
int n2 = n - n1;
while(n1 != 0){
c=c*2;
n1--;
}
while(n2 != 0){
d=d*2;
n2--;
}
if(c>d){
FinalNumber = c/d;
cout<<FinalNumber<<endl;
}
else{
FinalNumber = d/c;
cout<<FinalNumber<<endl
}
}
}
```

This program crashes when i enter the value of N above 30,what can i do to make it handle bigger numbers?And also is my program correct?

Comment: You need to post the error that it crashes with. If code chef doesn't tell you, paste it into a legitimate environment and get the error. Also, your code is very poorly formatted. Please fix that.

Comment: What is the exact input that causes a crash? Have you considered using a debugger?

Comment: n as 100 ,then the program crashes.

Comment: 100 is not the same as "above 30" is it? Would it be too difficult to supply all of the input?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, `n1` which is initially assigned `n/2` is used as a counter for a doubling operation on `c`: `c=c*2;`.

Depending on the value of `c`, `d`. and `n`, there could certainly be overflow happening which may cause a range of problems.

Note that these coding exercises are not a good way to learn how to program well.  Although they could be stimulating you in improving your skills, they often encourage users to write bad code quality.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `c` and `d` goes into integer overflow: your number is way too big to fit in a 32 bit integer number.

Websites like codechef expects you to think further: applying the brute force algorithm will only work on small inputs, you would have to find a better approach to solve the problem with the constrains that are given.